# How to provide "Login with my application" services

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid

Does any body know how can i configure my spring mvc application to provide services 
like login with google, login with facebook ?

I want to expose login with "my application" service to other third party applications.

Please guide, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Spring Social will give you what you need: http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/